# How do you use a slash in a Rails seed file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add a forward slash to one of my db seeds. Here is how I'm trying it:

```
Template.create! code: '<div style="background-image: url("/assets/forest-trees-hiker-hiking.jpg");></div>'
```

This results in spaces instead of slashes though...

```
style="background-image: url(" assets forest-trees-hiker-hiking.jpg");
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping it using \?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're very close with the suggestions noted in the comments, but you're missing one closing quotation mark after the semicolon:

```
"<div style='background-image: url(\"/assets/forest-trees-hiker-hiking.jpg\");'></div>"
```

Note that the entire div is wrapped in double quotes, and the style is wrapped in single quotes, which can be nested without confusion. But since you need to nest another string within those strings, you must escape the quotes around the url, in order to tell the program that you are not closing one of your existing quotation marks.

Comment: Still can't get it working mate. This is what I have now https://gist.github.com/colmtuite/55b5f8f111f16347698d

Comment: Interesting, and you're still getting the `unexpected '\n', expecting =>` error? Can't seem to reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: Ah, wait, I think I may see another problem with the code in your gist. For this section: `"background-image: url(\"/assets/forest-trees-hiker-hiking.jpg\");"` , you have escaped double quotes inside double quotes, meaning that both doublequotes will render in the saved html which results in the same issue described above. In this case I believe you would need to use escaped single quotes like so: `"background-image: url(\'/assets/forest-trees-hiker-hiking.jpg\');"`

Comment: For more info, [this article](http://blog.opensourceopportunities.com/2007/10/nested-nested-quotes.html) is fairly old but provides a much more thorough explanation of nesting quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As @usmanali wrote, you have to use backslash escape sign `\`

This should works for you: `Template.create! code: '<div style="background-image: url("\/assets\/forest-trees-hiker-hiking.jpg");></div>'`

More reading: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes

Comment: When I try that I get a syntax error: unexpected '\n', expecting =>

Comment: could you try this: `"<div style=\"background-image: url(\"\/assets\/forest-trees-hiker-hiking.jpg\");></div>"`

Comment: This is what I have now guys - https://gist.github.com/colmtuite/55b5f8f111f16347698d